# shape too large to be a matrix on python

Tags: python, machine-learning

There's a similar request with actually the same title, but unfortunately it does not meet my needs.

To those familiar with Machine Learning, I'm trying to implement the sigma update step for a 2D Gaussian Mixture Model. The problem I am having is that I cannot subtract a vector `InitMu` with a shape `(8,2)` from  `GenXn` with shape `(5000,2)`. What I thought of doing was:

```
aux2=np.zeros([N_data,SubC,Dim])
aux2=(GenXn[:,np.newaxis]-InitMu)
```

and I get the error on the title: ValueError: shape too large to be a matrix.

Could anybody help me please? Thank you.

Comment: Are you sure its the second line, which makes the problem? And what does the first one do, when aux2 is overwritten in the next line?

Comment: Hi allo. Yes it says that the problem is in the second line. I wrote the first line just to give you a sense of the shape of aux2. It seems I cannot subtract GenXn from InitMu. Thanks.

Comment: If the first one has the same shape, it cannot be a matrix because it has 3 dimensions. But I do not know which of the objects throws the exception. The usual numpy message would be more like ``shapes do not match`` or something similar.

Comment: Try breaking this up into individual operations: first reshape GenXn, save it in a temp variable, and check the properties of that.  *Then* try the subtraction.

Comment: Thanks, I have already solved the problem by messing with expectation values rather than by coding.